# angular 6: making button works to display data

Tags: angular, html-table, angular6

My table includes an '**Acknowledge**' button at the end of each row, that is supposed for the user to click and there will be output *'by (whoever clicks the button)'*.

my problem is that my button did not work since there is no error in console. Below as attach is my table in html and the js. Please note, im very new in angular 6 and I already tried several ways but did not work.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PagesService } from "../pages.service";

declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-alert',
  templateUrl: './alert.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./alert.component.scss']
})
export class AlertComponent implements OnInit {

  data$:object;

  constructor(private data: PagesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getAlert().subscribe(data => this.data$ = data);
    $('#example').DataTable({
     "pagingType": "full_numbers",
      "scrollX": true
    });

    $('#example').find('button').click(function () {
    console.log($(this).after());
    $(this).next().remove();
    $('<p>By ABC</p>').insertAfter($(this));
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<table class="table" id="example" style="width:100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Device Type</th>
      <th scope="col">Map Type</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Latitude</th>
      <th scope="col">Longitude</th>
      <th scope="col">Result</th>
      <th scope="col">Last Updated</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngFor="let data of data$">
    <tr>
      <td>{{data.id}}</td>
      <td>{{data.deviceType}}</td>
      <td>{{data.mapType}}</td>
      <td>{{data.name}}</td>
      <td>{{data.lat}}</td>
      <td>{{data.lng}}</td>
      <td>{{data.result}}</td>
      <td>{{data.lastUpdate}}</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Acknowledge</button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">View</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: Angular does give you the solution to bind events on the elements. There is no need to use jQuery for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of click event handler.

```
<button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" (click)="clickMe()">Acknowledge</button>
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-alert',
  templateUrl: './alert.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./alert.component.scss']
})
export class AlertComponent implements OnInit {

  data$:object;

  constructor(private data: PagesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {    
  }

  clickMe(){
// Your logic
  }
}
```

More Info is available [here](https://angular.io/guide/user-input).

Comment: unfortunately i already did this solution, even before i put the question on stackoverflow. do u have any other solution that i might can follow, sir?

Answer (score 0):

In your `HTML`.

```
<td><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" (click)="btnClick()">Acknowledge</button></td>
```

And In your `component.ts file`. Under the constructor code.

```
btnClick(){
   alert("It works... ");
}
```

Comment: @Nurfarahin Nadhirah Can you please update your status ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a click attribute to your button like so:
 `(click)="console.log('Hello World!')"`

You can replace the `console.log()` with a function like: `onCLickedAcknowledge()` and have it declared in your component.